# 'mdls' and 'mdimport' interaction: good practice question

Tags: macos, terminal, spotlight

Am I correct to assume that, in order to ensure a query in the terminal such as:

```
mdls -name kMDItemContentCreationDate /var/log/system.log
```

always returns the actual creation date of said file (provided it exists), I should always force Spotlight to import this information first via:

```
mdimport -r /var/log/system.log
```

?

I am interested strictly in obtaining, from the Terminal, that specific piece of data.

This seems to be the conclusion based on [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10038766/using-mdls-command-to-generate-a-metadata-report) SOV post, especially since the Spotlight indexing may ignore some folders.

Comment: I've never seen mdls fail to retrieve something as basic as creation date. Do you have a reproducible situation where your indexing is broken for an ongoing basis? Maybe fixing spotlight with `mddiagnose` would be easier than forcing an import for every query - but I guess if you do the query seldom, it might not be a large performance hit.

Comment: Oh no - I didn't stumble upon such a case. All I am trying to do is to "bullet proof" my approach...by "doing the right thing". I am writing some scripts that will deploy a product on a non-trivial # of systems  and I am relying on this information (overwrite an older version of the file with a newer one). This should happen for exactly two files, when an app starts...typically once or twice a day. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `stat` instead of `mdls` on a system running the 64bit kernel.

```
stat -f "%B" file
```

will return the creation date or birthtime in seconds since epoch (Unix/Epoch time). A human readable output can be produced with

```
stat -f "%SB" file
```

You can also format the output of this command by adding the -t option (see man 3 strftime).

On a system running the 32bit kernel, you need to use `GetFileInfo`.

```
GetFileInfo -d file
```

The output from `GetFileInfo` can be converted to Epoch time by running the output though the `date` command.

```
cdate=$(GetFileInfo -d file)
date -j -f "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S" "$cdate" +%s
```